# Wordpress copy in /test folder is not working after duplicator plugin action

Tags: wordpress

I used the duplicator plugin to copy my website to the /root/test folder. After runnning installer.php it and entering the correct database (new one) it shows a **page 404**. My goal is the run a 'beta' site where I can do all the edits I want before making it visible to public.

I am using the following url: [www.healthclubone.nl/test/](http://www.healthclubone.nl/test/)
Via **FTP** it seems that alle files have been copied correctly.

Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Best,
Robin

Comment: Did you also import the old database-entries?